# Angular 9 + NGINX - Issue with loading subroutes (returns MimeType error)

Tags: angular, nginx

So I'm getting issues with MimeType. My .js files are returning my index.html file because they can't be found. I realized that the URL of the .js files are trying to be served from
domain/route/route2/bundledjsfile.js
but when I visit it, like I said it returns HTML instead of JS. However after changing the route in the address bar, I noticed d
domain/route/bundledjsfile.js returns the actual minified js.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
06:12:19.128 polyfills-es2015.3fd94ed6a324eee92aec.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
06:12:19.128 main-es2015.0b1d748ffcf78a2a0b26.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

This only happens when I have a child route trying to render a component

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'dashboard/guilds', component: GuildsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }];
```

I am unsure how to fix this, because I have my server block location set up like this:

```
location /intellectual {
    alias /var/www/intellectual-developers/intellectual/;
    try_files $uri $args $uri$args/ $uri/ /intellectual/index.html;
  }

location /api/intellectual {
    rewrite ^\/api\/intellectual\/(\w+)$ /api/intellectual/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
}
```

Where /intellectual is the Angular app being served.
This issue also only happens when I visit main routes of my app, for example, my base url provided by NGINX is /intellectual, and Angular routes are /guild, /dashboard, etc. and those work fine because the JS/CSS files return correctly. However, if I try to visit a child route, like /intellectual/guild/my-guild, or /intellectual/dashboard/my-dashboard, it will throw the error. So I don't know what to do to fix this. I know it's a path issue.

Comment: Try `root /var/www/intellectual-developers` instead `alias /var/www/intellectual-developers/intellectual/;` in your first location. Additionally, use `$uri$is_args$args` instead of `$uri$args`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I tried it and it didn't work. Same thing happens

Comment: Than it is an Angular related issue. I'm not familiar with angular, maybe [this](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) link could help you?

Comment: were you able to fix this @AnsonFoong

Comment: @Nicholas Not necessarily, but I reconfigured my NGINX and had my app's location block files for "/" instead.